# Identifying points where lines intersect in one direction in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets, and I need to identify the index point(s) at which the values in dataset1 become >= than the values dataset 2. So in a (very simplified) example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(0,6))
df["data1"] = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
df["data2"] = [0,3,3,3,3,3]

print(df)
```

```
   data1  data2
0      0      0
1      1      3
2      2      3
3      3      3
4      4      3
5      5      3
```

I would want it to return a value of 3 (i.e. the index where the lines cross).

The problem is that the data I'm using oscillates (see the picture) and I only want the index values of the crossing point in one direction. (so, values for x at points a to c on the graph)

[image: a comparison of a sawtooth graph and a linear(ish) graph].

at the moment, I'm using a really long winded workaround:

```
import pandas as pd


def missing_elements(L, start, end):
    if end - start <= 1:
        if L[end] - L[start] > 1:
            yield from range(L[start] + 1, L[end])
        return

    index = start + (end - start) // 2

    # is the lower half consecutive?
    consecutive_low = L[index] == L[start] + (index - start)
    if not consecutive_low:
        yield from missing_elements(L, start, index)

    # is the upper part consecutive?
    consecutive_high = L[index] == L[end] - (end - index)
    if not consecutive_high:
        yield from missing_elements(L, index, end)


def intersections(l):
    result = []
    x = list(missing_elements(l, 0, len(l) - 1))  # Lists all the values which
    # Don't appear in the in input list
    result.append(max(x) + 1)
    for _ in range(100):
        try:
            x = list(missing_elements(x, 0, len(x) - 1))
            #            print(x)
            result.append(min(x))
        #            print(result)
        except:
            pass
    result.sort()
    return result


df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0, 6))
df["data1"] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df["data2"] = [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
print(df)

intersect = df.index[df["data1"] >= df["data2"]].tolist()

result = intersections(intersect)
print(result)
```

But I'm sure that there's a better way of handling this. Please can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've extended your data a bit:

```
data1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5]
data2 = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
df = pd.DataFrame({"data1":data1, "data2":data2})
print(df.head(8))

   data1  data2
0      0      3
1      1      3
2      2      3
3      3      3
4      4      3
5      5      3
6      0      3
7      1      3
```

Create a new column with the difference between data1 and data2:

```
df["diff"] = df["data1"] - df["data2"]
```

Then you need to create two masks. The first will find out when data2 is greater than or equal to data2.

```
mask1 = df["diff"] >= 0
```

The second will determine when the previous difference was negative.

```
mask2 = df["diff"].shift() < 0
```

Then apply the mask.

```
df = df.loc[mask1 & mask2, ["data1", "data2"]]
print(df)

    data1  data2
3       3      3
9       3      3
15      3      3
21      3      3
27      3      3
33      3      3
```

This will give you the rows only on the upside. The whole code is:

```
data1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5]
data2 = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
df = pd.DataFrame({"data1":data1, "data2":data2})

df["diff"] = df["data1"] - df["data2"]

mask1 = df["diff"] >= 0
mask2 = df["diff"].shift() < 0
df = df.loc[mask1 & mask2, ["data1", "data2"]]
```

Comment: This is fine, but I'm not sure I understand, how does this do something that `df.index[df["data1"] >= df["data2"]].tolist()` doesn't?

Comment: Your equation df.index[df["data1"] >=df["data2"]].tolist() returns all values where data1 >= data2. My formula above only returns values where data1 >= data2 AND the previous value data1 < data2. This means you are only getting the index locations where data1 moves from being less than data2 to being equal or greater than data2. I hope I read your question correctly and this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Ah! I get it now. Thanks!